# Elasticsearch query to search from different fields non-strictly

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, querydsl, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm relatively new with elasticsearch and have been working with elasticsearch in python. What I had was people's data in csv format which I had converted to json and had added to elasticsearch index. 
The fields are the following:

```
'Last Name (Legal Name)', 
'First Name', 
'Middle Name', 
'Other Last Name', 
'Business Mailing Address City Name', 
'Business Mailing Address State Name',
'Business Practice Location Address City Name', 
'Business Practice Location Address State Name', 
'Authorized Official Last Name', 
'Authorized Official First Name', 
'Authorized Official Middle Name', 
'Authorized Official Title or Position'
```

What I want to put in the query is something like "Name City". For Example, "Clinton Adams Hamilton" where Clinton Adams is the name and Hamilton is the city. In most of the cases I won't be sure which is the first name or which is the last, so I will need to match from all the fields.

What I've used till now is something like this:

```
"query":{
                "query_string":{
                    "fields": ['Last Name (Legal Name)', 'First Name', 'Middle Name', 
                             'Other Last Name', 'Business Mailing Address City Name', 
                             'Business Mailing Address State Name',
                             'Business Practice Location Address City Name', 'Business Practice                            
                              Location Address State Name', 
                             'Authorized Official Last Name', 'Authorized Official First Name', 
                             'Authorized Official Middle Name', 
                             'Authorized Official Title or Position'],
                    "query": "(Clinton) AND (Adams) AND (Hamilton)",
                    }
                }
```

The following query works fine if I search the exact name and City from the database but if I have a spelling mistake in the name or if in some name the first name is abbreviated, it doesn't give the expected results. For example if the query is something like "Clinton A Hamilton", it wouldn't match with any documents. I can't use the `OR`operator as there are multiple people with similar names, so all of the parts of the query - first name/last name and city are important. I would want the query to fetch the most relevant record from the index.

I tried my best to explain the situation. In any case, feel free to ask if anything isn't really clear. Appreciate your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why you include all the fields when all you want to consider - if I understood you correctly - is the name of the person and the name of the city.

Comment: @glenacota Alright, I get the point that cities and names can be queried as different queries, maybe using the ```bool``` operator. Could you suggest what might be a good way to move ahead after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do is to refine your document mapping. In particular, I would think about whether it makes sense to keep so many different name-related fields (e.g., first name, last name, middle name, official authorized ...), or if it would make sense to filter some and merge something else. For example, would this document mapping make sense for you?

```
{
  'name', 
  'business_mailing': {
    'city',
    'state'
  },
  'business_practice_location': {
    'city',
    'state'
  }
}
```

Point is, you should optimise your data based on the queries you'd like to run against it.

With the mapping above, then you could run a [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) (a `must`) that contains two `match` queries, possibly with [the `fuzzyness` option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness) configured so as to account for typos. E.g.,

```
{
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'must': [{
        'match': {
          'name': { 'query': 'Clinton Adams', 'fuzzyness': 'AUTO'
        }
      },{
        'match': {
          'business_mailing': { 'query': 'Hamilton', 'fuzzyness': 'AUTO'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Another solution could be to use the `copy_to` mapping option and define a new queryable field that includes the values of the name fields and city fields. Here is the link to the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/copy-to.html

Comment: I changed the mapping and i am able to get the desired results using bool and multi_match as now I have two full name fields (basic Full name and the authorized one) and also two location fields(Mailing Address and business practice address). The results I'm getting now are not in decreasing order of ```_score``` metric. Could you suggest a way so that I can get the max score document as output? Thanks.

Comment: You mean to get only one result, i.e., the one with the highest score? In this case, you can set the "size" of your query to 1. (anyway if your question is answered, would you mark it so? :) )

Comment: Yeah, the problem was occurring because I was using ```helper.scan``` function in python. If i used the basic ```es.search```, I get the required results. 
Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should give a try to the multi-match query, especially the `cross_field` type that is suited for your use case. [Documentation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields).

It will handle all your searched fields as one blended field.

But if you keep your operator "AND" a query for "Clinton A Hamilton" will not match a "Clinton Adams / Hamilton" document. 
I think you should go for the standard OR operator. It will give you the first relevant document in first position. Exact matches first and partial ones after.

If you know for sure that a lot of your users will use diminutive form for the first name you should consider creating a special analyzer to index the diminutive form.

Here is an example in a standalone index :

```
PUT diminutive
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "diminutive": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 3
        }
      }, 
      "analyzer": {
        "diminutive": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "diminutive"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "firstname": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "diminutive",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could then use your diminutive analyzer in a field for `'First Name'` ( see documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html)) and add the subfield in the multi-match query.

It's maybe a lot of informations / concept to handle, but I think it should be a good start for your use case.

Comment: This is a good approach and multi_match with cross fields can be a helpful. What worked for me is by changing the mapping and concatinating the different columns. Thanks for the help.